# Twitter rate limit

Tags: twitter

I am whitelisted in Twitter, and I have this "traffic heavy" application that just makes 2 request to find out how many users 2 people have.... the traffic currently is killing the 150 request limit per hour.

How do I authenticate my requests so that twitter knows I am whitelisted?

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=chavezcandanga

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=luischataing

I wish to authenticate those for this simple project http://250mil.com

Thanks!

Comment: How can you kill the 150 request limit if you only make 2 requests? Or did you mean to say that you do 2 requests every second? or ... ?

Comment: I am getting 20.000 visits per day on that URL... so I make 40.000 requests

Comment: outside of white listing, why dont you store the user counts in a database? then you can just cache the values for 30 seconds or a minute and not have to worry about white listing or reaching too many requests. i doubt the users would notice the difference anyway. in fact if you include a timestamp on the counts and you could do a neat little animation from start to finish using all of the values from the table.

Comment: I wanted to avoid "complicated" the app, since it was just going to be a 6 days thing... but I guess I have no other solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

See how to authenticate on the [Twitter API Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth), it explains every method available to authenticate and how to issue such authentication requests.

Comment: I was there... I didn't see a single example that I can use... I prefer their old docs :S

Comment: Hell yes, the new page layout is a bust.